# Visual Studio Excel Add-in Development - Unable to activate Windows Store App Error

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, excel-addins

I am trying to build my very first Excel Add-in Development project.
I have add the Add-in ribbon and a button.

When I try to run (in debug mode) It gives me following error.

> Unable to activate Windows Store app
>   'Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Excel', The  activation
>   request failed with error 'Element not found'.

When I open the Excel App my add in is installed as COM Add-in.
[image]

But I only need to open the excel with my add-in for testing.
As others suggested I tried to 
Clean the solution,
restart the machine, 
remove obj & bin folders,
run the project in release mode then debug mode.
Nothing works.

```
namespace ExcelAddInHW
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the related code with me?

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT Hi, I added no new code at all, I created a new project then added a ribbon then tried to run the project.

Comment: According to your code, I can do nothing. So can you tell me what you want to do directly?

Comment: I'm trying to run the project but it fails giving me the above error. 'Unable to activate Windows Store app 'Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Excel', 
Normally when you run the project an excel opens up with the newly created add-in. Even if I create another project and try to run it, it doesn't open an excel instead gives me this error.

Comment: Did you happen to get this working?

Comment: @jmgardn2 I'm afraid no. I couldn't get a fix for that.